# Windows SSL Certificates in C# Metro Application

Tags: c#, ssl, microsoft-metro, ssl-certificate, certificate-store

I'm new with Windows Metro Apps development and the key problem I faced is that it is not possible in Metro app to force server SSL certificate verification like it can be done in classic applications.

So, the question is: How to make a WebRequest via https using certificates which installed on local machine?

After importing specific certificates to the windows via mmc.exe Internet Explorer 10 stops reporting certificate problems, but my Metro Apps still throws exceptions about certificate problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution appeared pretty simple. The only thing needed is to add a capability for Metro application called "Shared users certificates"